# Upvote / downvote - history?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, upvotes

Sometimes a question receives very similar or even equal answers.

In some situations, one answer might be downvoted for no obvious reason. Most the time I expect that this downvote comes from the creator of the other answer in order to make his answer look more promising in order to be preferred by the TC.

Is there a way (given one has enough reputation) one can see WHO was actually downvoting and maybe remove any downvotes that just serve competition purposes?

If not, I would like to request this feature, excluding "own" posts of course.

---

As of the duplicate-report:
No, I'm not talking about EVERY user being able to see WHO downvoted his post. Only users with a very high rep can see this EXCEPT on answers/posts created by themself. So, no civil-war :P

---

There are some good arguments against this I didn't think of right away. So, leaving this post for historic-purpose if somebody has a similar idea in the future.

Comment: There is no such feature. Introducing it would lead to civil war and blood in the streets.

Comment: (Your assumption about where downvotes come from isn't necessarily always correct, btw. If a question is really, really bad/lazy, and the millionth duplicate of something simple, then some people will downvote even correct answers to the question.)

Comment: I don't think so. I think people that would have this due to reputation and experience would deal with it in a propper way.

Comment: You'd think someone with this much rep and as long as you've been a user here would know why this would be a bad idea........

Comment: Well if there's a duplicate answer to the question, that alone *is reason to downvote it*, so I don't understand why you'd think there wouldn't be any reason to downvote it.  As a rule, you should *always* be assuming that votes are cast in good faith, by someone who honestly believes that the post isn't useful.  Don't just assume that votes are malicious because it's not how you personally would have voted.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of possible duplicates, I just picked one out. On MSE there are also a bunch of discussions, going back to 2009 even, explaining that only developers have access to that information, **by design**.

Comment: Deal in a proper way? What if the other answerer downvotes you, but for a valid reason (your answer isn't as awesome as you think it is,for instance). Knowing who downvoted it will lead to unwarranted gripe, resentment, and potentially revenge votes. There is truly no benefit that would outweigh the massive headaches this would cause....

Comment: As of the duplicate-report: No, i'm not talking about EVERY user beeing able to see WHO downvoted his post. Only users with a very high rep can see this EXCEPT on answers/posts created by themself. So, no civil-war :P

Comment: @dognose Not even moderators can see the data. And the question of the duplicate doesn't really matter, just the bottom line of the answer matters: *"There are... a bunch of other reasons to keep voting anonymous; search this site or [the mother meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested."*

Comment: @dognose That would lead to somewhat less fights, but it still means that the only result of this feature existing would be fights; it's the only possible consequence here.  It'll also result in users demanding that other people tell them who voted on their posts, and people obliging.

Comment: `I think people that would have this due to reputation and experience would deal with it in a propper way` I think you're seriously overestimating the maturity of higher-rep users here... it's *very* tough to stay objective toward someone you know just downvoted you. And even with the limitation, it would be awful: people would be afraid to downvote, knowing that they can be outed by anyone with the right reputation. There'd be lots of strife, for no discernible benefit. What good would this do?

Comment: "people would be afraid to downvote, knowing that they can be outed by anyone." - that is a valid thought.

Comment: Downvoting shouldn't be discouraged, it is an extremely useful (and probably underused) tool.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I think if we set cut-off at 900K that should be fine. All the user above seem to be trustworthy :)

Comment: @Alexei that we can agree on, yeah!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.**

There is no feature like that, and we don't need or want it. It'd be actively harmful to say the least.

---

Votes are anonymous to prevent users from smashing each others head in. That also goes for high-rep users (*maybe even especially for those?*). Currently even elected moderators cannot see the vote history (*I think that's employee-only*), and the reasoning is "Civil war? No thanks!".

Introducing this would also lead to a ton of noise. People'd start asking for justification more often (*"Why did you downvote my question/answer!?"*), and would probably also resort to revenge downvoting, **which'd completely invalidate the voting system!**

The reason why asking for justification would be a problem is that it's **noise**, plain and simple. People'd feel pressured to spend time on justifying their actions, and they'd also limit themselves drastically in their moderation effort by only using downvotes on the true garbage.

Pressuring people? We don't want to do that. Limiting people? We don't want to do that either, especially when it comes to downvotes, which are super underused already, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Well as I said, it should not be possible for users "on their own posts" - that indeed would cause revenge-votes etc. However @Pekka is right by saying, that this might cause users to "not downvote" because they know somebody ("high rep users") can see their downvote. I just stumbled accross a post, where 3 times the SAME answer was giving, and two received a downvote, even if they have been earlier in time. (All were technically correct, so it lookes like the 3rd person has copied one, then downvoted the two existing answers.)

Comment: @dognose I can totally see where you're coming from with this proposal, but the problem is that we'd trade "targeted downvoting" for "censorship", and I'd prefer dealing with the former over dealing with the latter. Voting is an iffy topic :)

Comment: Maybe the solution to "this" would be: "Sorry, you cannot vote on questions where you have added an own answer" - but I sometimes upvote other answers as well, so not really an option.

Comment: Maybe... Like I said, iffy topic.

Comment: @dognose A person providing an answer to a question is quite likely to have a very informed opinion on the quality of other answers.  They're often in a much *better* position to evaluate other answers than other readers.

Comment: @Servy I absolutely agree.